# Can't find Step-Down VREG in D2PAK with "strange" pinout

Tags: voltage-regulator, identification, pinout

I'm repairing a device. I have found burned VREG.

Seems like simple adjustable step-down voltage regulator with integrated switch in 5-pin D2PAK/TO-263.

IC package was damaged and label isn't readable. "No problems" – I thought...

But! When I trace nets I have found, that pinout of VREG is "strange".

Look at pic. I noted my pinout with **red**.

[image: Strange VREG]

All 99% of such VREGs has same pinout. And other 1%, that I was found – has another pinout, but not needed.

**Anyone know such VREG? Ty!**

Comment: Are you sure it's a switcher?

Comment: Can you provide photos of the device and of the part of the PCB where it was mounted? Maybe even provide the type/model of the device you are repairing.

Comment: @Andyaka Sure it's switch. Input and output power lines, and, also, ground, easy determinable. And there is the typical schematic, like on my pic.

Comment: What's the Vin and what's the Vout nominal values? Do you have this information? And what's the maximum current the regulator should provide? Is this known to you?

Comment: @LorenzoDonati [PCB Pic.](http://imgur.com/lNEi5DI) Custom made device. Vin=10..16V (car), Vout=5V.

Comment: [Another Pic, with comments.](http://imgur.com/LaFOIv0)

Comment: I believe this is a Chinese device- I've run into it before. Can't recall the P/N unfortunately. It's beefier than the usual TI nee NS buck regulator;.

Comment: Found one. XL4015. Can be found in Chinese Step-Down modules.

Comment: Good find! You could answer to your own question, then, so that this thread could be useful also for other people visiting the site (an you could gain some rep too).